# XPath not working properly in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xpath

I am using Kanna in swift to get data from html.

When I do "html/body" as Xpath, I get everything in the body from the site.

When I do "/html/body/center/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]" I get nothing, however when I use a xpath tester and fill in "/html/body/center/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]" I get data.

Swift code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    if let doc = Kanna.HTML(url: (NSURL(string: "URL")!), encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        print(doc.title);

        for link in doc.xpath("/html/body/center/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]") {
            print(link.text)
           // print(link["href"])
            // print("test");

        }

    }


}
```

Comment: The above code works for me with a simple HTML page. Can you please post the source of an HTML page for which it is failing?

Comment: Hi, here is an example site: http://roosters.roc-teraa.nl/rooster_uitwisseling/techniek-technologie-college/2P0/2016021520160415/index.htm if you do XPATH:  /html/body it shows all data but if you go further like /html/body/table[1]/tbody/tr[14] It doesn't show anything in swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `tbody/` segment from your XPath. The source of the link you posted had no `<tbody>` element:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html><head>
<title>Klasrooster, van 15-02-2016 t/m 15-04-2016</title>
<meta name=generator content="Paralax Rostar Eduflex Versie 3.508">
<!-- Dit bestand is automagisch aangemaakt. Handmatige wijzigingen kunnen verloren gaan. -->
<style type=text/css>
<!-- 
body, th, td { font-family: arial, verdana, geneva, times, helvetica,  courier; font-size: 8pt; }
-->
</style>
</head><body><table border="1" width="100%">
<tr><th>Klasrooster, van 15-02-2016 t/m 15-04-2016</th></tr>
<tr><td><a href="2P02025.htm">TT.12MB.b</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="2P02002.htm">TT.12ME.a</a></td></tr>

<!-- skipping many rows -->

<tr><td><a href="2P02202.htm">TT.RES2</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="2P02038.htm">TT.RES3</a></td></tr>
</table>
<!-- XREF START -->
<table border="0" width="100%"><tr><td>[Vorige periode]</td><td><a href="../../index.htm">Overzichtspagina</a></td><td>[Volgende periode]</td></tr></table>
<!-- XREF END -->
</body></html>
```

I suspect you are using the "Inspect" feature of Firefox or Chrome to view the HTML of the page you are parsing. The problem with this is that it is showing the browser's DOM model- not the original source. Use the "View Source" feature to see the original HTML code.